"Angular: After trying to register a new user, an error occurred: 'FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/configuration-not-found)'."
I am trying to implement authentication functionality in a modern Angular project. After I try to register a new user, I get an error: 'FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/configuration-not-found).' I don't understand why it is not working; it seems to be correct.
"I'm using Angular 18 and I am also using the '@angular/fire' library.
This is how my app config looks:
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'auth-domain',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'storage-bucket',
  messagingSenderId: 'messaging-sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
};

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),

    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
  ],
};

this, how i use it in my service:
export class AuthService {
  firebaseAuth = inject(Auth);

  register(
    email: string,
    username: string,
    password: string
  ): Observable<void> {
    const promise = createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      this.firebaseAuth,
      email,
      password
    ).then((response) =>
      updateProfile(response.user, { displayName: username })
    );
    return from(promise);
  }
}


and this how i use it in my register component:
 authService = inject(AuthService);

  form = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl(),
    email: new FormControl(),
    password: new FormControl(),
    confirm_password: new FormControl(),
  });

  onSubmit() {
    const form = this.form.getRawValue();

    this.authService
      .register(form.email, form.username, form.password)
      .subscribe(() => {
        //router
      });
  }
}

I've tried to put my imports in importProvidersFrom() in my app config, but it didn't work for me. I'm new to Angular and don't know how to correctly initialize my Firebase app in the project. I think this is causing the error.

Did you activate the authentication method in firebase?

@Raffael, thank you for your answer. Now I feel like a complete idiot, but my authentication is working

Thanks to the comment from @Raffael, I've noticed that my email authentication was not activated. After activating the email authentication option in the firebase console, everything works as it should.
